# x-editable in recursive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using angular recursive templates to generate a tree structure. I want to use x-editable for single leaf renaming. But the whole tree gets to "edit state" instead.

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bLhvjd5/

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_category_renderer.html'" />
</ul>
```

< script type="text/ng-template" id="tree_category_renderer.html">

```
< div>
    <span class="name" editable-text="data.name" e-form="textBtnForm">{{data.name}}</span>
    <button ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()">edit</button>
</div>
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="data in data.children" ng-include="'tree_category_renderer.html'" />
  </ul>
</script>
```

Any ideas how to fix this?